# Неопределенна ссылка на <<xdr_float>>

Tags: linux, c, makefile

При сборке make файла с rpc программой, не получается его собрать, в терминале выдается эта ошибка. Обновлял некоторые пакеты и тд, но ничего не меняется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]